# big O notation in Gilbarg & Trudinger

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, asymptotics

In the PDE book by Gilbarg & Trudinger (2001) the following notation is used for example on page 380 (and elsewhere in chapter 15)
$$b = O(\lambda |p|^2)$$
and
$$\bar{\delta}b \leq O(\lambda |p|^2). $$

What is the difference between "$=$" and "$\leq$" here?

My guess is that $f(p) = O(|p|^2)$ means $C^{-1} |p|^2 \leq f(p) \leq C|p|^2$ for some $C>0$ and all large $p$ but I am not sure since this doesn't seem to be clarified anywhere in the book.